# Can anyone recommend a good online calculator for travel time within the solar system?

Tags: physics

I'm trying to figure out how long it would take to travel to saturn with a skyhook launch from moon orbit.

Comment: I think the best way to go about asking this question is to read previous questions and answers here about skyhooks and the Moon and see if you can estimate how much velocity is even possible, and then read previous questions and answers about detla-v required to go from one place to another, then when you reach a limit ask a more specific question here.

Comment: there's this: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9692/12102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maybe this will help](https://transfercalculator.com/calculator/lowRes.html)

You can basically assume starting from a ~385000 km altitude Orbit around earth. For "how much time" it does not matter, how you get there. The speed you leave the earth-moon-sphere of influence with (V_infinity) is the same, no matter if you had a stop at moon.